# Spring Security : impossible to do Authentication in front end side

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot backend and a frontend based on Angular 5.
i want to do authentication and authorization with Spring Security.
i want the login form to be customized in Angular(http://localhost:4200/login).
i want to have users and their passwords and roles in database.
i can't understand how to tell Spring that the Login page is in a different domaine(in frontend side).
should i define a /login in a RestController class or there is a /login by default in Spring Security that allows users to be authenticated ?
Please Help.

#### i started with a test confguration : users in memory:

```
package smart.syndic.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{   

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
    {   
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("1234")
            .roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login/**", "/administrateurs/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users").permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/forbidden")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter

Answer (score 0):

If you have choosen to split backend and frontend to 2 different servers (ex. localhost:8080 and localhost:4200), then it would be more elegant to assume that backend does know nothing about frontend. In this approach backend should return status 401 ([like here](https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bfwg/security/auth/RestAuthenticationEntryPoint.java)) when request is unauthorized and your frontend should handle this be redirecting user to /login page.

In order to do this in spring you could do sth like what was in example from comment.

1. Implement [filter](https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bfwg/security/auth/TokenAuthenticationFilter.java)
2. Tell spring to use this filter like here [WebSecurityConfig](https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bfwg/config/WebSecurityConfig.java)
3. [Create controller for login](https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bfwg/rest/AuthenticationController.java)